# Why does tar hang with 100% CPU if files list has leading spaces

Tags: tar

Tar hangs with 100 % CPU load if the `--files-from <LISTFILE>` option is used and the `<LISTFILE>` contains leading spaces. Why is that?

To reproduce: Given two files `file1` and `file2` of arbitrary content and a file `list` with the following content:

```
file1
  file2
```

When I issue `tar czf test.tar.gz --files-from list`, the command will never finish, and system load is ~ 1.

If I change `list` to read

```
file1
file2
```

The above `tar` command completes without problems.

This happens on both Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS server edition and on my Ubuntu 14.10 desktop; both have GNU tar 1.27.1.

Comment: Works on OSX/bsdtar 2.8.3

Comment: And Arch/GNU tar 1.28

Comment: I built GNU tar 1.28 from source and can still reproduce the behavior. Puzzles me.

Answer (score 2):

I have reproduced this behaviour. Looks like a bug.

I fix it downgrading to tar v1.26, from here https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/tar/download (if you use Debian/Ubuntu, download your corresponding .deb version and install with dpkg -i).

Comment: If you start with your workaround, this would look more like an answer. Just delete everything up to and including "`As a temporary workaround,`" and from "`,it's pretty`" until the end. You can then use the comments on your own post to give information about you considering this being a bug. That is also where you put thanks, if you feel chit-chat is needed (read [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)). Remember this is a Q&A site not a forum.

Comment: Thanks for the indications, @Anthon. Just read them today! (never too late?)

Comment: Indeed never to late. Should I say: welcome back?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the results that you are getting, although I can get tar to throw an error when doing what you describe.

Ignoring that, providing a list with spaces before a file name is incorrect; whitespaces are not insignificant in Unix. If you tell tar that a file is called "  file2" then tar looks for a file called "  file2" and if it does not not find one, there is an error.

If you rename file2:

```
mv file2 '  file2'
```

and then run tar, it works.

Either way, tar should error out, not crash as it is doing on your system.

Comment: I get the error message ("No such file or directory") too if I issue the command `tar czf test.tar.gz "file1" "  file2"`. Using the `--files-from` option, tar will still hang if there are leading spaces.

Comment: what version of tar are you using. I am not able to replicate the hanging behaviour.

Comment: GNU tar 1.27.1 (Ubuntu package) as well as 1.28 (which I compiled from source). It happens on my laptop and on a server that I administer (so I don't think it's something to do with my personal profile).